# Granular Eclipse Luna preference files (.epf) require seemingly random preferences?

Tags: eclipse, settings

I am trying to make granular EPF files and I am finding that they require seemingly random settings (in addition to those I actually want) to avoid the empty list message.

```
Empty list.
Note: Not all preferences support individual import.
```

Here is an example EPF I have made.

```
# Eclipse Preferences: C/C++ console colors
# kaltendorf

# Sorry but Eclipse seems to need these to import...
file_export_version=3.0
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/c_operators=230,230,250

# These are the real preferences of interest
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/buildConsoleErrorStreamColor=225,30,70
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/buildConsoleBackgroundColor=53,53,53
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/buildConsoleOutputStreamColor=235,235,235
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/buildConsoleInfoStreamColor=140,175,210
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/buildConsoleProblemWarningBackgroundColor=94,66,2
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/buildConsoleProblemHighlightedColor=240,142,162
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/buildConsoleProblemInfoBackgroundColor=7,32,88
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/buildConsoleProblemBackgroundColor=92,23,3
```

and another.

```
# Eclipse Preferences: Code formatting (tabs, 120char column indicator)
# kaltendorf

# Sorry but Eclipse seems to need these to import...
file_export_version=3.0
/instance/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/content_assist_proposals_background=30,30,30

# These are the real preferences of interest
/instance/org.eclipse.ui.editors/spacesForTabs=true
/instance/org.eclipse.ui.editors/printMarginColumn=120
```

`file_export_version` makes some sense to me and I can understand that certain settings may only make sense in sets but that does not seem reasonable for `content_assist_proposals_background` and `c_operators`.  Is there something that can be done about this?  It takes me awhile to figure out which setting it is that it wants and it also muddies up the otherwise granular files.